# Does changing a price set for an event retroactively change reports?

Tags: civievent, civireport, reports, price-sets

If a price set is changed in terms of prices etc will that affect reports for past events that used that same price set?

If it did do that we would have a huge list of price sets just to maintain reporting!

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost certainly no, but it might depend on the report you're looking at. Specifically, financial transaction data is stored with the full amounts, not just a reference to the price set, so you can't change a contribution by changing the priceset it came from.

In other words, it's safe to update a priceset from one year to the next for an annual event, for example.

Comment: Does that also mean it's safe to change to a different price set on a live contribution page without affecting existing contributions?  Or even remove the price set and use the Fixed Amounts section?

Comment: Yes, probably. I wouldn't delete a price set, that can cause messes, but you can stop using a price set on a contribution page and use the fixed amounts section instead. The 'probably' is in case you've got some other customization or extension that is counting on a particular configuration.